# How to use RabbitMQ broker in Java application

Tags: rabbitmq

How to use RabbitMQ message broker in Java application? I have not found any document or link to understand how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [plenty](http://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html) or RabbitMQ documentation.

In particular, you may be interested in the [Java client API guide](http://www.rabbitmq.com/api-guide.html) and the [javadocs](http://www.rabbitmq.com/releases/rabbitmq-java-client/v2.0.0/rabbitmq-java-client-javadoc-2.0.0/).